# ActionbarCompat not showing Action-Icons

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar-compat

When using *ActionbarCompat* as *Actionbar* BackPort I am having the problem that action-icons do not show up - same code/res works with actionbarsherlock.

Am I doing something wrong or is this not yet supported? I am also missing the whole Menu/MenuItem `getSupportMenuInflater()` part that ABS has in ActionBar compat - can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question was already answered in [Actionbar not shown with AppCompat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18510337/actionbar-not-shown-with-appcompat).

Add the following namespace to the "menu" item in your xml file

```
xmlns:compat="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Then change the "showAsAction" attribute to use the new namespace

```
compat:showAsAction="ifRoom"
```

Here's a full example with one item in the menu, with the changes on lines 2 and 6 (from [Actionbar not shown with AppCompat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18510337/actionbar-not-shown-with-appcompat))

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:compat="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
    <item android:id="@+id/action_whatever"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_whatever"
      android:title="@string/whatever"
      compat:showAsAction="ifRoom"  />
</menu>
```

Comment: Please add the essential parts of the links as part of your answer.

Comment: Updated to include full answer and the example, as suggested by CSchulz.

Answer (score 0):

When using the new *ActionBarActivity*, you no longer need `getSupportMenuInflator`. Your code should look like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

When calling `invalidateOptionsMenu` with *ActionBarActivity* you do need to use the new support version:

```
supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
```

Those are the only two main differences between *ActionBarSherlock* and the new *ActionBarActivity* that I have found.

Comment: hm my code was looking that way, but the actions-icons did not show up

Comment: Can you post your menu xml and onCreate method? Are you extending ActionBarActivity?

Comment: really hard to extract and I am basically back to ABS where this just worked out of the box and wait for the AppCompat to mature I think before giving it another try ;-)