# Actionbar not shown with AppCompat

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat, android-appcompat

I am backporting my app to API7 with AppCompat and have a problem with the actionbar.

When I use `FragmentActivity` the actionbar is shown on my phone (API18), but with `ActionBarActivity` it shows up as the optionmenu by pressing the menubutton.

On the emulator with API7 the actionbar is always shown as an optionsmenu.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Use the compat name space for your menu items like this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:compat="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
    <item android:id="@+id/action_whatever"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_whatever"
      android:title="@string/whatever"
      compat:showAsAction="ifRoom"  />
</menu>
```

Answer (score 6):

Related to [a duplicate that points to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20512644/action-buttons-doesnt-show-up-on-action-bar), I was having trouble making my buttons appear as action items instead of overflow items, despite having showAsAction set to `always`. I managed to coerce it by extending my activity with `Activity` instead of `ActionBarActivity`. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23089547/difference-between-activity-actionbaractivity), this is acceptable if you don't need to support api levels below 11.

`...extends ActionBarActivity`:

[image: extends ActionBarActivity]

`...extends Activity`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I do debug with Doogee Valencia Y100Pro, and menu as "three  little square" not visible, but when I extended my MainActivity with `android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity`, then I obtain text/icon menu in action bar. Next [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMBGV.jpg) and menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_update"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_refresh"
        android:title="@string/action_update"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
</menu>
```