# error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'showAsAction'

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm trying to make action bar to appear always.

I'm getting:

```
error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'showAsAction'
```

My menu codes are:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:Logo="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item
    android:id="@+id/answered"
    android:icon="@drawable/answered"
    android:title="answered"
    Logo:showAsAction="always"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/notanswered"
    android:title="notanswered"
    android:icon="@drawable/notanswered"
    Logo:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

target=android-15
Minimum Sdk is 8

Comment: Try `logo` instead of `Logo`.

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22044847/action-items-not-showing-in-actionbar-with-showasaction-ifroom

Comment: are you using appcompat ?

Answer (score 0):

Since ur min target is 8 but you need to ensure Honeycomb = API level 11 = Android 3.0.x for **showAsAction**

Comment: And how to use it for lower (api 8 )

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your project's build target(not your min-sdk version) is set to Honeycomb(Api Level 11). Remember to do a clean after you change the build target.

Also, to enable your app support action bar below 3.0 you need to use the app compact v7 from the support library(appcompat_v7). Import the library to your workspace and reference it in your project.

Check this [link](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/08/actionbarcompat-and-io-2013-app-source.html)