# Android option menu is not showing on API 2.x.x

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-optionsmenu, android-appcompat

Im using appcompat v7 for rendering the action bar on my Android project. This works very well on versions 4.x but the options menu (only the options menu) is not exibithed on 2.x.x versions. What is the problem?

My list_team.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_profile"
    android:title="@string/menu_label_profile"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    app:showAsAction="never"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_about"
    android:title="@string/menu_label_about"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>
```

My Activity

```
public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_team);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.list_team, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: You mean your action_about is not showing on the Action Bar? Or you are not able to open the overflow menu (and see your action_profile item)?

Comment: Hi @ianhanniballake im not able to open the overflow menu for action_profile. It is not showing on older versions.

Comment: And what happens when you hit the hardware menu button?

Comment: It is not showing the optionsmenu. Only show the action bar and the action_about.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Actionbar not shown with AppCompat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18510337/actionbar-not-shown-with-appcompat)

Answer (score 1):

Try to delete these two attributes `android:showAsAction=""` and keeping only these `app:showAsAction=""` instead.

According to the [Google Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html):

> If your app is using the Support Library for compatibility on versions as low as Android 2.1, the showAsAction attribute is not available from the android: namespace.

You can also change the `orderInCategory` of *action_about* to 1.

Answer (score 1):

Based on this code, you are missing `super.onCreateOptionsMenu()` in your override:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.list_team, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

And you should also only use `app:showAsAction` namespace as has been previously suggested.

Comment: app:showAsAction Attribute is missing the Android namespace prefix?

Comment: Are you using the support library? Look at the above code. You need the `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` line in your menu xml file.

Comment: Yes, I am using support library.

Comment: Can you reference me anything why android: over app: or vice versa? Thanks

Comment: See the other answer to this question. When using the support library, you have to use the support namespace instead of android.

Answer (score 1):

Devices with Android 2.X usually have a hardware menu button. In that case the overflow menu icon is **not** displayed (at least by default, not sure if there is a toggle for this in appcompat, though there was in ActionBarSherlock).

Nevertheless, tthe options should be accessible when pressing the menu button. May that be the case?

Comment: but, where is options menu in android api 10? Is it bottom left corner?

Comment: @levi It appears from the bottom of the screen when you press the menu key.