# android action buttons not visible on low resolutions

Tags: android, android-actionbar, action

I'm developing an app and testing it directly on my device (HTC One S). Everything is fine until I run it my device (or with higher resolution), but if I try to run the app on another device with a low resolution, I cannot see the action button on the top right.

This is how the UI should be (and it's on my device):

[image]

And this is how it appears on devices with lower resolution:

[image]

I tried even with Eclipse virtual device, by setting up a 240x320 or 320x480 or 480x800 but nothing... I still don't see the action buttons

I looked for similar questions, the only one I found is this one: [Actions Buttons in Android not visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18510337/actionbar-not-shown-with-appcompat) , but does not work.
Cannot figure out what's the trick!

Comment: What 'device with a low resolution' are you testing it on? What Android version is it running?

Comment: Maybe the device have a *hardware menu button*, so it will not show the more button on actionBar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="always" />
```

Make sure your menu item has the 'showAsAction' set to 'always'. Failing that, ensure the smaller device your using does not have a hardware menu button enabled.

Comment: That was the point! The real device with low resolution which I installed my app on has the hardware menu button!
I feel a little fool :)Thank you guys!