# AppCompatActivity custom ActionBar buttons do not appear on Android 4.1.2

Tags: android, android-actionbar, appcompatactivity, android-4.1-jelly-bean

It works fine on 5.1, but does not on 4.1.2

What am I missing?

Here is the activity xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:myApp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/transfer"
        android:title="@string/transfer"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_transfer"
        myApp:showAsAction="always" />
    <item android:id="@+id/refresh"
        android:title="@string/refresh"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_refresh"
        myApp:showAsAction="always" />
    <item android:id="@+id/about"
        android:title="@string/about"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_info_details"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        myApp:showAsAction="never" />
    <item android:id="@+id/help"
        android:title="@string/title_activity_help"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_info_details"
        android:orderInCategory="101"
        myApp:showAsAction="never" />
    <item android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:title="@string/settings"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_info_details"
        android:orderInCategory="102"
        myApp:showAsAction="never" />
    <item android:id="@+id/search"
        android:title="@string/search"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_info_details"
        android:orderInCategory="103"
        myApp:showAsAction="never" />
    <item android:id="@+id/logout"
        android:title="@string/logout"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_info_details"
        android:orderInCategory="104"
        myApp:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

And here is my activity class (witch extends another activity that extends AppCompatActivity):

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_activity, menu);
    return true;
}
```

I am using the following appcompat library:

```
'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
```

Comment: add layout file my_activity

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks for your reply. I did what these two answers suggested:

[How to force use of overflow menu on devices with menu button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9286822/how-to-force-use-of-overflow-menu-on-devices-with-menu-button/11438245#11438245)

[Actionbar not shown with AppCompat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18510337/actionbar-not-shown-with-appcompat#18510391)

To summarise the solution:

1. I changed "myApp" to "compat" in the activity xml (fixed the missing buttons)
2. I added this code

   ```
   try {
       ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(this);
       Field menuKeyField = ViewConfiguration.class.getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");
       if(menuKeyField != null) {
           menuKeyField.setAccessible(true);
           menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false);
       }
   } catch (Exception ex) {
       // Ignore
   }
   ```

to my base activity (which every other activity extends) which extends AppCompatActivity (fixed the missing menu)

Now it works in both 5.1 and 4.1.2

Comment: Adding that code I believe only works with `ActionBarSherlock`.

Comment: @ Jared Burrows I do not know about ActionBarSherlock, have not tried it. But it certainly works with AppCompat.

Comment: I am thinking that changing `"myApp" to "compat" in the activity xml` fixed it. However, I am not sure, I have seen this before. I have already switched to the `Toolbar`.

Comment: At first I thought it would, as well. But I quickly discovered that it only fixed the problem with missing buttons. For the menu button to appear, I had to add the Java code.

Answer (score 4):

You should use Toolbar instead.

Put this in your XML:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@id/toolbar"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />
```

This code goes in your activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    if (toolbar != null) {
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getTitle());
    }
}
```

Than you just inflate your Menu:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        onBackPressed();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: He is not using the `Toolbar` and he is only trying to make the `overflow` menu show.